# Как сосканировать строку в переменные по шаблону?

Tags: c++, строки

Нужна функция, которая из строки (не с ввода, а переменной) может получать значения и записывать их в переменные по шаблону, такому же как в функциях `printf`, `scanf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`std::sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) для ввода данных из строки по заданному шаблону:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    const char* str = "1 2 3";
    char a;
    int b;
    float c;

    std::sscanf(str, "%c%d%f", &a, &b, &c);
    std::printf("a is: %c\n", a);
    std::printf("b is: %d\n", b);
    std::printf("c is: %f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Также советую обратить внимание на классы [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) / [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), которые предоставляют возможность ввода данных из строки (и вывода в строку, соответственно) по аналогии с классами `std::istream` / `std::ostream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "1 2 3";
    std::istringstream iss(str);

    char a;
    int b;
    float c;

    iss >> a >> b >> c;
    std::cout << "a is " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b is " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c is " << c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **(i/o)stringstream** не будут работать работать с разными сепараторами. а вот за **sscanf** спасибо это то что нужно.